# Oracle | No Listener error while connecting from Excel

Tags: excel, database, oracle, listener

I am  trying to connect to Oracle DB from Excel, on windows 10 machine. Initially I had issues with drivers & this was resolved once I installed Oracle client.

Now, I am getting another error stating - "ORA-12541: TNS:no listener".
I manually created below listener file by googling the format -

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0(PORT = 1528))
      )
      (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC))
      )
    )
  )
```

And this is the TNS file -

```
TSTIM =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = TSTIM.<host>.com)(PORT = 1528))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = TSTIM)
    )
  )
```

I am able to connect to the same DB from SQL developer & from java program. I am not able to connect via Excel. Please help.
Files are saved at - **D:\app\client\Admin\product\12.2.0\client_2\Network\Admin**

[image]

Comment: Is Excel, SQL Developer and Oracle all running on the same host? Oracle has several methods for accepting connections. TCP/IP requires a listener process, but if the client and server are on the same machine there is a shared memory mechanism that can be used as well. SQL Developer might be using that if it's on the same machine as the database.

Comment: No, Oracle server is installed somewhere else. I am trying to access it from the SQL developer/excel installed on my local machine. I installed some driver packages provided by Oracle on my local, as part of oracle client installation. Even before installing oracle client, i could access the DB from SQL developer. But I am not able to access through excel.

Comment: Does the TNSNames.ora file have the correct IP address and port numbers?
Can you examine what parameters SQL Developer is using?

Comment: Yes. TNS file is configured correctly. I was getting an error for TNS earlier, which was resolved post configuring TNS.ora by referring the SQL developer.